# Is internet access needed for CA signed applet?

Tags: java, applet, sign, jar-signing

We coded a java applet and signed it through a Certificate Authority, Entrust.
When the applet is deployed through any browser, we can see in java console logs that a request is made to the CA:

```
network: Connecting http://ocsp.entrust.net/ with proxy=DIRECT
security: OCSP Response: GOOD
```

However, our client has some computers in an intranet *without* internet connection.

So, is there a way to avoid any internet request to CA server?

Answer (score 3):

You will find this option from Java Control Panel >> Advanced tab

Perform Certificate revocation checks on:
Publishers certificate only;
All certificates in the chain of trust (default and recommended);
Do not check (not recommended)

http://www.java.com/en/download/help/revocation_options.xml

However, you will have to change it for each computer in the intranet.

Comment: Good to know :)
But still, no option in manifest.mf, jnlp file or whatever?

Comment: from the applet side, I don't think there is. it seems like it will defeat the purpose of it

Comment: Seems logical indeed.